# Magento 2.3.x best practice to update the website in production mode

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.2

What are the best practices to update the website in `production` mode?

---

For example, if I need to update the `less files, images, js etc.` what would be the best approach to update the website in `production` mode?

Comment: How to compile less files in the production mode?

Answer (score 0):

In case of css changes should happen inside your theme `app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/web/css/source/_filename.less` or `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/css/source/file.less`

The same applies for images and js on the respective paths.

Once you modify or create these files, you can then deploy to production only the static files with the command `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy Language_TAG -f` (ex language. en_US).

This is the correct way of how you do it.

Comment: In the production mode how to compile less files?

Comment: using the command i wrote. more reference here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-static-view.html